# Firebase - Unable to insert new data, keeps updating root node

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase realtime database is like this:

```
https://......
      |
      |
      transaction
      |
      |--0
         |
         |--0 -- "Name":"abc"
            | 
            |
            1 -- "Name":"def"
```

Now I want to insert a data. This is my code:

```
firebase.database().ref("transaction/0").set(
     {
         "Name":"ghi"
     },
)
```

---

My expected output:

```
https://......
      |
      |
      transaction
      |
      |--0
         |
         |--0 -- "Name":"abc"
            | 
            |
            1 -- "Name":"def"
            |
            |
            2 -- "Name":"ghi"
```

My actual output:

```
https://......
      |
      |
      transaction
      |
      |--0 -- "Name":"ghi"
```

How do I create a new node everytime I insert a record?

Answer (score 0):

To add a sequential auto-incrementing key to the `transaction` node, you will need to:

1. Read the entire `transaction` node
2. Determine the next available key
3. Write the new key, ensuring that nobody has created it in the meantime

This can be done by [using a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) call in the database API. This also means you will have to read-and-write the entire `transaction` node.

Using such sequential numeric keys is common in many programming tasks, but it's considered an anti-pattern in Firebase. To learn more on why that is, and why using Firebase's native `push` operation is preferred, have a look at  [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).